# How to pass parameter value from make command line to compiler

Tags: c, batch-file, makefile

I'm try to build a project which have several variants.
And each variant got a different const table.
so I want to use macro(eg. VARIANT) to control the const table that would be compiled.

```
#if (VARIANT == 1)
static UINT8 const variant_1_serial_no[6] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06};
#else if (VARIANT == 2)
static UINT8 const variant_2_serial_no[6] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66};
#endif
```

I use batch file to invoke the make utility.
In batch file I use set /p to give user a chance to choose the variant no.

```
set /p VARIANT_TYPE=1:variant1;2:variant2;others quit(for example:input 1 chose variant1)
call make.bat %VARIANT_TYPE%
```

Then I try to define this macro as compiler input.

```
-DVARIANT=$(VARIANT_TYPE)
```

and it doesn't work at all, because this $(VARIANT_TYPE) is illeagal here.

I use Borland make utility ver5.2 and IAR compiler.

Does anybody know how to pass this parameter to compiler ?

Comment: What is the error message? In principle this should work (but don't pass `%VARIANT_TYPE%` as an argument).

Comment: Shouldn't `variant_1_serial_no` and `variant_2_serial_no` be same ? Else  there is no need for having a `MACRO`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `variant_1_serial_no` and `variant_2_serial_no` to be same.
Instead of passing a value to the macro and trying to compare, you can do as below.

```
#ifdef VAR1
static UINT8 const variant_1_serial_no[6] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06};
#elif VAR2
static UINT8 const variant_2_serial_no[6] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66};
#endif
```

When compiling to select the first set of constants use

```
gcc -DVAR1 <file_name>
```

else to select `VAR2` use

```
gcc -DVAR2 <file_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your batch file you invoke `call make.bat %VARIANT_TYPE%`; if `VARIANT_TYPE` is set to 1, then this expands to `call make.bat 1`, which is clearly not right (this will ask make to build the target `1` which is obviously not what you want).

If you want to set a variable on the make command line (assuming Borland make uses the same methods as traditional make) then you have to make it a variable assignment:

```
call make.bat VARIANT_TYPE=%VARIANT_TYPE%
```

so that the actual invocation is `make.bat VARIANT_TYPE=1` or whatever choice is made.